# Why wont my app process my intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, url-scheme, main-activity

I have this app:

```
import android.R.drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        String b64encoded = null;
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        b64encoded = data.getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart();
        if (b64encoded != null) {

            if (data.getScheme() == "cqrsa") {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Authentication");
                builder.setMessage("Clicked: " + b64encoded);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setIcon(drawable.ic_lock_lock);
                builder.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
            if (data.getScheme() == "sqrsa") {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Authentication");
                builder.setMessage("Scanned: " + b64encoded);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setIcon(drawable.ic_lock_lock);
                builder.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Authentication");
            builder.setMessage("No data was supplied");
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setIcon(drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            builder.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }    

    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
}
```

and then I defined the intent in AndroidManifest as:

```
<activity android:name="eu.sebbe.www.qrsaauthentication.MainActivity" android:label="AuthTestLabel">
        <intent-filter>
             <data android:scheme="cqrsa" />
             <data android:scheme="sqrsa" />                        
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

However, when testing the application, the Intent catcher only hangs and show the screen "AuthTestLabel".

It seems like MainActivity doesn't get executed at all.
What Im doing wrong?

I created a blank Android Project (without any Interface) since this app should only calculate a one time password and show it onscreen in a dialog box (or put it in clipboard) depending on if the app was called from a clicked link or a scanned QR code. (this is why I define 2 urlhandlers, sqrsa and cqrsa)

What is the problem with the app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing the String with `==` operator in the if statement,in that condition may return `false`

you need to compare the string with `equals()` like change this  `data.getScheme() == "sqrsa"` with `(data.getScheme().equals ("sqrsa"))`

Comment: Works perfectly. I don't understand why it would make a difference to compare with == or equals()? Anyone that has a explanation?

Comment: Yeah go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java